# JNI wrapper for C++ libraries and undefined symbol error

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, undefined-symbol

I want to write a simple JNI wrapper for using Festival text-to-speech (or any other) library which has a C++ API. I have the following files:

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main {
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("TTSWrapper");
   }
   private native void FestivalSayHello();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Main().FestivalSayHello();
   }
}
```

**Generated Main.h:**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Main */

#ifndef _Included_Main
#define _Included_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Main
 * Method:    FestivalSayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_FestivalSayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**FestivalWrapper.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include "Main.h"
#include "include/festival.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_FestivalSayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
    EST_Wave wave;
    int heap_size = 210000;  // default scheme heap size
    int load_init_files = 1; // we want the festival init files loaded
    festival_initialize(load_init_files,heap_size);
    festival_say_file("/etc/motd");
    festival_eval_command("(voice_ked_diphone)");
    festival_say_text("hello world");
    festival_text_to_wave("hello world",wave);
    wave.save("output.wav","riff");
    festival_wait_for_spooler();
    return;
}
```

**makefile:**

```
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

all : libTTSWrapper.so

libTTSWrapper.so : FestivalWrapper.o Main.h
   g++ -m64 -fPIC -shared -o $@ $<

FestivalWrapper.o : FestivalWrapper.cpp Main.h
    g++ -fPIC \
   -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include" \
   -I"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/festival/src" \
   -I"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/speech_tools/include" \
   -L"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/festival/src/lib" \
   -L"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/speech_tools/lib" \
   -lFestival \
   -lestools \
   -lestbase \
   -leststring \
   -lncurses \
   -c $< \
   -o $@

Main.h : Main.class
   javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*
```

The following error occurs on runtime:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/workspace/TTS/jni/libTTSWrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8EST_WaveC1Ev
```

Could you please help me in figuring out where the problem is? And I am not sure if -m64 and -fPIC are necessary.

Note-1: `nm libTTSWrapper.so | grep EST_Wave` lists the symbol that causes the error, even if I delete the -L and -l lines.

Note-2: Festival is a combination of static libraries.

Note-3: This problem is not library-specific, I faced the same problem with another library (Ekho), too. The problem is that I don't know how to link the third party libraries.

**UPDATE:** I am still not sure, but I guess that the problem is because Festival is not linked with `-fPIC` option. Although the symbols occur in the resulting shared library, I think they cannot be referenced correctly. I reached this while I was trying to make a simple executable that uses a shared library which is linked to a static library, in pure C. I had to create the **.a** file from an object file built with `-fPIC` option, and also the shared library needed the `-fPIC` option, too.

Comment: Question is way too specific to an external library.. You need to provide CODE.. What is the error? Is code causing it? Is it just your makefile that cannot find files? etc.. Just the makefile alone isn't good enough.

Comment: The exact error is always relevant

Comment: @Brandon: I have edited the question, and added source code.

Comment: You could make use of a tool like [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) to make this a whole lot simpler - without sacrificing performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your code is packaged, but the package name is very important for JNI. Also I would not recommend using the default package (at any time, but especially in this case :p)

Suppose that your package is called
`package groove.FestivaWrapper`

Then your JNI call has to look like this 
`groove_FestivalWrapper_FestivalSayHello`

Otherwise JNI will not figure out what to call.

Comment: Would it still compile if there is a package problem as you mentioned?

Comment: If I remember correctly yes. If the .h matches the .cpp then the compiler won't complain. Then at runtime the JNI runtime won't find anything and cause hard to debug pain.

Comment: With the error message that you get this might not be the problem however.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The first problem is that when you are building `FestivalWrapper.o`, it *ignores* the `-L` and `-l` options - they're only used by the linker, not by the compiler. Those options need to be passed to the linker. Your makefile should look more like:

```
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

all : libTTSWrapper.so

libTTSWrapper.so : FestivalWrapper.o Main.h
   g++ -m64 -fPIC -shared -o $@ $< \
   -L"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/festival/src/lib" \
   -L"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/speech_tools/lib" \
   -lFestival \
   -lestools \
   -lestbase \
   -leststring \
   -lncurses

FestivalWrapper.o : FestivalWrapper.cpp Main.h
    g++ -fPIC \
   -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include" \
   -I"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/festival/src" \
   -I"/home/TTS_tools/Festival/speech_tools/include" \
   -c $< \
   -o $@

Main.h : Main.class
   javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*
```

i.e. you have to move the `-L` and `-l` options to the item that generates the `.so` file, which is when the linking is performed.

Your second issue is that you've not compiled festival with `-fPIC`. Yes, this will prevent linking because *all* `.so` 64bit files must be compiled with `-fPIC` if they're to be ABI compilant. You'll get an error like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../festival/src/lib/libFestival.a(festival.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../festival/src/lib/libFestival.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

The libraries do not follow standard configure conventions - i.e. trying to set `CFLAGS` before running the configure script simply does not work.

To build `speech_tools` and `festival` with `-fPIC` for the `.a` files you do:

```
export CC_OTHER_FLAGS=-fPIC
```

before running `configure` for each package. That will ensure that the `-fPIC` flag is passed into all stages of compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, the "export..." command did not work for the Ekho TTS library. So I am afraid this procedure will not work for all libraries, if I am not doing anything wrong.

Comment: The speech_tools and festival packages do not follow `configure`/`autoconf` specifications, which is why you end up having to use the `CC_OTHER_FLAGS` when building those to get the `-fPIC` flag in the build. Ekho TTS uses the standard autoconf mechanism, so setting `export CXXFLAGS="-O -fPIC"` and `export CFLAGS="-O -fPIC"` should have the desired effect with that library.